# Composer could not find a composer.json file even when the file exists

Tags: json, laravel, composer-php

I have installed Laravel and and I am playing around with it.

I am following the tutorial :-

http://geekanddummy.com/how-to-laravel-4-tutorial-part-3-using-external-libraries/

I need a new library and have added that in composer.json.

But when I run

```
php composer.phar update
```

I get the following message :-

```
Composer could not find a composer.json file in
```

What do I need to do to get this corrected..?

Comment: Are you in your laravel root directory?

Comment: yes,i have composer.json, composer.lock, composer.phar, server.php, phpunit.xml, gitignore, gitattributes all in the directory

Comment: hey this worked after i deleted the composer.json and saved it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting the existing composer.json after copying the content and then saving a new file with the same name works.

Answer (score 5):

I'm the author of the tutorial you link to (hope our [Laravel tutorial series](http://geekanddummy.com/?s=laravel) is of some use, by the way).  I can't quite tell from your answer whether you restored all the content of the original composer.json file when you created a new file of the same name...?  You definitely shouldn't need to nuke the composer.json file and start again.  As you probably know, that file contains all the Composer-based dependencies for your Laravel project, so you would of course lose significant functionality if you were to wipe it and leave anything out when you start again.

The error message looks to me like you're either in the wrong directory or it's a permissions problem with the composer.json file.  It's too late to be certain now, but if you come across the problem again, try running:

```
chmod a+r composer.json
```

at the console/ssh shell before running `composer update`.  This restores read permissions (for all users).  You may also wish to check file ownership.  (Both commands assume we're in a Unix/Linux system, so YMMV.)

Watch out also for instances where you're running a Composer command with the `global` parameter.  This will cause an change that relates to wherever you've installed Composer, rather than the directory you're currently working in.

Note that you can also update using the `--working-dir` parameter, thus:

```
php composer.phar --working-dir=/path/to/laravel/project update
```

Hope this helps.

Rob

Comment: Sorry for the necromancy but I was running into the same problem. I was able to get it to work only if I supplied the --working-dir. I must have installed it globally (windows). Is there a way to still run composer while in the working directory without having to supply the additional flag?

Comment: Afraid I've never used Composer under Windows and am not sure how it behaves in that environment.

Answer (score 0):

If your on windows (at least in my experience) you actually use just 'composer', not composer.phar/.json or any extension.

```
composer update
composer dump-autoload
```

This is all I need to type in to be able to access composer in my laravel directory.

Comment: This completely depends on how Composer was installed. And if the way calling Composer works and returns a genuine complaint from it about things being wrong, then the method to call Composer was correct.

Comment: Yes absolutely, but she/he never clarified how composer was installed.  They never stated they tried just 'composer' in the command line so I thought they may have installed it the same way I have.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, tried several many solutions that worked for others but not in my case.
then some-one told me to drop the 'php' and '.phar' from my command.  i.e. directly use

composer update
composer create-project    etc.etc.

and to my surprise it worked..

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally, and for reasons that remain a bit vague, restarting the server seems to solve the issue. That step might be worth trying before making changes to file permissions.

Answer (score -1):

Go to https://git-scm.com/download/win
Then download related version and run your composer command inside the git bash

Or else you can use vscode bash;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWKzU.png)

Comment: Why should installing any Windows program resolve the given problem? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it